# IIS7 to IIS8.5 config file error

Tags: iis, web-config, windows-server-2012-r2

I converted an application on iis7 with framework 4 for iis 8.5 with framework 4.5 but gives me an error on a section of web.config:

*The configuration section 'handlers' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration*

web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add verb="*" path="s/*" type="shortenDownload.mydownload" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
  <add verb="*" path="download/*/*/*.*" type="downloadHelper.mydownload" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="*" path="downloadPhoto/*/*/*.*" type="downloadPhotoHelper.mydownload" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*.asbx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
  <add verb="GET" path="SearchSiteMaps.axd" type="Microsoft.Web.Preview.Search.SearchSiteMapHandler" validate="true"/>
  <add verb="*" path="Diagnostics.axd" type="Microsoft.Web.Preview.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsHandler" validate="true"/>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</handlers>
```

The error gives either IIS Manager or the browser.

Comment: Where did you put them? (in which config section)